# EntityExistsException when using @EmbeddedId with dual-side bidirectional association

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

This exception's answers are flooded over Stackoverflow but have not a single matching my problem case. I have two entities `Post` and `User` which are having `ManyToMany` relationship but the relationship table has two extra fields: `voted_at` and `vote`.
So, I need to have an additional entity class `PostVote` which would have `EmbeddedId`. `PostVote` table is the table which would hold the `user` who voted for the `post`

```
public class PostVote implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PostVoteId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("postId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime votedAt;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean vote = true;

    public PostVote() {
    }

    PostVote(Post post, User user) {
        this.post = post;
        this.user = user;
        this.id = new PostVoteId(post.getPostId(), user.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PostVote that = (PostVote) o;
        return Objects.equals(post, that.post) &&
                Objects.equals(user, that.user);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(post, user);
    }
}
```

The `PostVoteId` entity

```
@Embeddable
public class PostVoteId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Integer postId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    PostVoteId(Integer postId, Integer userId) {
        this.postId = postId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public PostVoteId() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PostVoteId that = (PostVoteId) o;
        return Objects.equals(postId, that.postId) &&
                Objects.equals(userId, that.userId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(postId, userId);
    }
}
```

I am following [Vlad Mihalcea article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/). Now, to add votes to the `post`, I have `addVote` method in `Post`.

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer postId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PostVote> voters = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addVote(User user){
        PostVote postVote = new PostVote(this, user);
        voters.add(postVote);
        user.getVotedPosts().add(postVote); //problem here
    }
}
```

The service method which is voting for the post is:

```
Post post = postRepository.findById(postId);
final User user = userRepository.findById(123);
post.addVote(user);

postRepository.save(post);
```

The above code gives the error

> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.sample.entities.PostVote#com.sample.entities.PostVoteId@4ba].

**But** if I remove `user.getVotedPosts().add(postVote)`(keep single-side bidirectional association) then it works fine.

The existing solutions didn't help. Maximum says to check the `GenerationType` strategy and the implementation of `equals` and `hashcode`. But in my case, both are set fine.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK `5.3.9.Final`